# Get HTML in C# from page that Load Dynamic Data

Tags: c#

I am trying to get data from a website an C#:

https://www.trendyol.com/TRENDYOLMiLLA---Trend-Kombinler/ButikDetay/168286

It looks like this website gets the data from an ajax call after the page loads. When I call this code:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    return client.DownloadString(URL);
}
```

It gets the base HTML but does not process the ajax call and fill in the data. Is there a way to get the final page after rendering from code?

Comment: If you are interested in data, I would look to see what URL they hit to get the data and request directly that.

Comment: As far as I know, you can only retrieve dynamically generated data by actually opening the page, e.g. by using selenium and the likes.